# mysql from many big tables make one columns same

Tags: mysql, mariadb

i have 20 big tables with 2millions line each.

sample

```
id    |   more_id   | more_id_2  | text 
2            1          2         some_text
```

i need make them as one table.

this code is making very long time from phpmyadmim:

```
insert into `one_big_table` (`more_id`, `more_id_2`, `text`) select `more_id`, `more_id_2`, `text` from `each_table_1` ;
```

from console this code is makin very long time and result is

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

id - autoincrement primary index,
more_id - index,
more_id_2 - index,
text  - full text index

What i need to make it faster should i delete all indexes or is there some easy way to do it?

Comment: two million isn't that big, but how do you combine both tables exactly, by joinig them or by union them?

Comment: You may want to add the indexes after you create the combined table.

Comment: im not combining them i need to make one table from 20 tables. I do this code to make one big table from other 20 one by one by this code 
insert into `one_big_table` (`more_id`, `more_id_2`, `text`) select `more_id`, `more_id_2`, `text` from `each_table_1` ;

Comment: You are combining the tables into one. Probably you need a union or process the tables selerately with insert ... select ...

Comment: UNION is your friend, but any of the tables canhave the same id, with dfferent text, so it is no wonder that you get duplicate ids, also if the ids form the tabkles are a reference to other tables this gets a lot messier

Comment: code pls with union many tables in one table. Becouse i just see that union is useing for making select from diff tables

Comment: [CREATE TABLE ... SELECT Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-select.html) try this one also

Comment: instead of running this one piece of SQL 20 times, you can run it once with 20 `SELECT` statements all glued together with `UNION` (as @nbk says). `insert into one_big_table (more_id, more_id_2, text) SELECT more_id, more_id_2, text from each_table_1 UNION select more_id, more_id_2, text from each_table_2` ... etc
Also drop all indexes on `one_big_table` before merging everything, then put the indexes  back after will be faster.

Comment: Are these tables read only (like an archive)? Do they need InnoDB storage engine or doesn't it matter? Do they have all the same columns and definitions?

Comment: Tables not read only, i use mariadb InnoDB, They all same columns different definitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deletion of indexes solve my problem.